# Version Error when running nextjs with pm2 interpreter

Tags: node.js, next.js, pm2, nvm

my pm2 and default node version `v18.14.2`
my nextjs node version `v18.19.0`

Change the nvm version to `18.19.0` and run `npm install` and `npm run build`.
After that, change to `v18.14.2` and run `pm2 start npm --name test-web --interpreter /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/node -- start`.

Then the app runs, but a version error occurs.

```
test-web@0.1.0 start
next start -p 10102
You are using Node.js 18.14.2. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.
```

When using `pm2 show`, the version is `v18.19.0`. What am I doing wrong?

[pm2 show screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKK3D.png)